# Получение цвета и направления стрелки openCv python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

День добрый, требуется ваша помочь, нужно определить цвет фигуры и направления стрелки от 0 до 360 градусов.
Уже несколько часов думаю над этой задачей, ничего в голову не приходит.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

hsv_min = np.array((0, 50, 50), np.uint8)
hsv_max = np.array((187, 255, 253), np.uint8)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    img = cv.imread('img.png')
    hsv = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    thresh = cv.inRange(hsv, hsv_min, hsv_max) 
    contours, _ = cv.findContours(thresh.copy(),  cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    for cnt in contours:
        rect = cv.minAreaRect(cnt)  
        area = int(rect[1][0]*rect[1][1])
        if area < 300:
            continue
        box = cv.boxPoints(rect) 
        box = np.int0(box)
        cv.drawContours(img, [box], -1, (255, 0, 0), 2)
    cv.imshow('contours', img)
    cv.waitKey()
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: Примеры фигуры]
[image: Примеры фигуры]

Comment: Подход, который вы пытались реализовать может найти угол наклона отписывающего прямоугольника, но он не сможет определить направление стрелок. Т.е. может быть ошибка в знаке и в результате будет ошибка на 180 градусов. Представьте что зелёная стрелка указывает в строго противоположном направлении - угол наклона описывающего прямоугольника при этом будет такой же как и сейчас.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как стрелка наиболее насыщенный по цвету объект, то ее можно выделить в HSV пространстве бинаризацией по порогу. Используя дистанционное преобразование можно найти острие стрелки. Центроид стрелки находим через моменты. Далее, думаю, все понятно.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

file = "qpgqP.png"

original = cv2.imread(file)

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
(_ret, threshold) = cv2.threshold(hsv[:,:,1], 90, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
dist = cv2.distanceTransform(threshold, cv2.DIST_L2, cv2.DIST_MASK_PRECISE)
idx=np.argmax(dist)
y,x=np.unravel_index(idx, dist.shape) #corner position
color=original[y,x,:]
M = cv2.moments(threshold)
cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

print(180*np.arctan2(x-cX, y-cY)/np.pi, 'degrees')
print(color[::-1], 'rgb color')
```

Comment: Интресное решение! Никогда не сталкивался с `cv2.distanceTransform()`. Я использовал `cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack` для нахождения острия стрелки. Можете объяснить куда направлен угол 0 градусов? Судя по вашему решению вектор с углом 0 градусов указывает на север, а не на восток - я правильно понял?

Comment: Для данного скрипта угол 0 градусов соответствует стрелке, направленой вниз, вправо +90, вверх -+180, влево -90. Если надо другую систему отсчета углов - меняйте  местами числитель и знаменатель (а также x и cX и y и cY)  в предпоследней строке как надо.